# SPARQL - evaluate an IF-expression within a query

Tags: if-statement, websphere, sparql, rational-team-concert

I am working as an informal team lead (team handles specific type of tasks in the project) for a project which uses IBM RTC for change management.
Now, I have created various queries/reports to streamline how I get the information I need for the weekly status slides of my team.

The problem I encounter is the following.
In the the tasks there is an *"effective estimate"* (not an task attribute!) which is calculated as
"if 'correction'-value exists, then use 'correction'-value, else use 'estimate'-value".

So as soon somebody adds a "correction" then my "total estimates"-query will no longer provide the correct result.

**What I expect/need:**

- The sum over all tasks.
- for each task the bigger value of Correction or Estimate shall be used
- output in hours (therefore the division by 3600000)

**possible solution in the query/report-editor:**
As I cannot query the "effective estimate", I did try to use a custom expression,
based on the SPARQL syntax I could find.
The report editor does validate this as formally correct, but as I have no SPARQL-experience I cannot tell where the actual problem is.

`SUM( IF($Task:Correction$ > 0, $Task:Correction$, $Task:Estimate$) ) /3600000`

**What I get:**

- I only get the sum of the 1 task where a Correction is already added.
- for comparison: The reports which do not use the "IF"-part provide correct results.

**What I already tried** (leading in the best case to the "What I get" above):

- IF($Task:Correction$ > 0, $Task:Correction$, $Task:Estimate$)
- IF($Task:Correction$ != 0, $Task:Correction$, $Task:Estimate$)
- IF($Task:Correction$ > $Task:Estimate$, $Task:Correction$, $Task:Estimate$)
- COALESCE ($Task:Correction$, $Task:Estimate$)

Comment: can you please provide some sample RDF data, ideally in Turtle or N-Triples syntax. And then the expected result please?

Comment: Unfortunately no.
I have only access to the "code" I use in the "custom expression".

Everything else in the queries/report-editors is more like graphical UI,
and the attributes as they are shown in the task items themselves.